# Will deleting all the firewalld files be enough to disable it?

Tags: linux, firewalld

Might be a silly question but I've accidentally locked myself out of my EC2 instance because I installed firewalld then rebooted my instance. Now I can't SSH into it, so what I did was clone a new instance, attach the volume from the original instance, SSH into and now I can see the firewalld files. If I delete them then reattach the volume to the original instance will that be enough to make sure it's no longer enabled on it?

Comment: did you tried just a reboot?

Comment: Rename /etc/firewalld dir to something. Thats enough.